# Let's Encrypt certificate on modulus.io

Tags: ssl, meteor, ssl-certificate, modulus.io, lets-encrypt

I've deployed a Meteor app on [modulus.io](https://modulus.io/) and would like to set up SSL with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

According to [Let's Encrypt's documentation](https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html), it seems that you need access to the server's command line to install their client. But, as far as I know, there's no way to access the server's command line on modulus.io.

Is there any way to get a Let's Encrypt certificate on modulus.io? If so, how?

Comment: Note that Let’s Encrypt  certificates are [**short lived**](https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#renewal) need to be renewed at least every 90 days.

Answer (score 5):

At this time Modulus does not support Let's Encrypt.
However, this summer (summer 2016) we will be adding support for this.

---

Edit: as of July 28, 2016 we have enabled Let's Encrypt for our Public Cloud.

You can enable this by going to your project dashboard, then the 'administration' section of your dashboard, then select `Enable Let's Encrypt`.

You just have to click the button.  That's it. We automatically renew the cert for you and everything.

More information on Let's Encrypt for our platform can be found [here](https://help.modulus.io/customer/en_us/portal/articles/2518372-let-s-encrypt).

Answer (score 2):

LetsEncrypt is a tool that simply generates certs and keys. Some of the magic is in the clients that can auto regenerate when certs expire but there is nothing stopping you from doing it yourself by hand. Be aware though that LetsEncrypt issues certs that expire in 90 days so you will have to repeat this process frequently until Modulus supports a client.

**Install LetsEncrypt**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
$ cd letsencrypt
$ ./letsencrypt-auto
```

*Note*: At the time of this writing Mac OS X support is very experimental. To ensure this installs correctly you may want to use a Linux distro

**Generate SSL Cert:**

`$ ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com`

**Copy into modulus admin**

```
# pbcopy is a Linux command that will copy the contents of a file to your clipboard
$ pbcopy < /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
$ pbcopy < /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
```

*Note:* You may need to create a bundle before copying. Instructions can be found [here](http://help.modulus.io/customer/en_us/portal/articles/1701165-ssl-setup-guide?b_id=9670).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I tried generating the certificate in a virtual machine, but got [this authentication error](http://pastebin.com/ucaPmKzc). Googling around didn't make me any wiser.